# Importdata from large xlsx file

Tags: performance, matlab, import, xlsx

I have xlsx file which contains 750,000x33 cells.

When I tried to use:

```
[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('*.xlsx','XLSX Files');

fid = fopen(FileName);
T=importdata(FileName);
```

The computation took over an hour.

Is there anything I can do to speed the process?

I also tried to use xlsread but it didnt work aswell.

- I have managed to importdata a 550,000x33 file before in few minutes, dont see a reason that the time it takes will grow that much.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way would be:

- using [`xlsread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) function for reading the data;
- having also MS Excel installed (is not mandatory, but it helps with the speed and the data loading options).

So, try this:

```
[file_name, path_name] = uigetfile('*.xlsx','XLSX Files');
[num, txt, ~] = xlsread(fullfile(path_name, file_name));
```

After this, you will have anything that could be converted to numbers in the numeric matrix `num`, and everything else as the string cell array `txt`. Check the function's help for further tuning of the data loading.

**Later edit:** If this is still slow, is most likely because `xlsread` is growing arrays in memory in basic mode, and the memory is fragmented, or too small. Options (they are not mutually exclusive):

- convert the file to .CSV, then use [`textscan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to load the data;
- close MATLAB and open it again, before reading the file (best way of defragmenting the array memory);
- increase the size of the virtual memory on your system;
- add more RAM to your machine.